# Javascript JSON : Getting NULL values while summing up the jsons arrays for every matching key found

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, null

I need to sum NUMERIC values in below arrays.Each array has 3 main keys on the basis of which we match the another json, these are"metric", "careerLevelGroups" and "careerLevel".

```
var input1 = // trimming down the input due character constraint

        [{
            "201806": 0,
            "201807": 0,
            "201808": 0,
            "201809": 0,
            "201810": 0,
            "201811": 0,
            "201812": 0,
            "201901": 0,
            "201902": 0,
            "201903": 0,
            "201904": 0,
            "201905": 0,
            "201906": 0,
            "201907": 0,
            "201908": 0,
            "201909": 0,
            "201910": 0,
            "201911": 0,
            "format": "number",
            "metric": "avgHeadcount",
            "careerLevelGroups": [{
                    "201806": 0,
                    "201807": 0,
                    "201808": 0,
                    "201809": 0,
                    "201810": 0,
                    "201811": 0,
                    "201812": 0,
                    "201901": 0,
                    "201902": 0,
                    "201903": 0,
                    "201904": 0,
                    "201905": 0,
                    "201906": 0,
                    "201907": 0,
                    "201908": 0,
                    "201909": 0,
                    "201910": 0,
                    "201911": 0,
                    "format": "number",
                    "careerLevel": "Senior Managing Director",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "Accenture Leadership - GMC",
                            "careerID": "0-GMC-10000025-GMC"
                        },
                        {
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "Accenture Leadership - 1",
                            "careerID": "1-SMD-10000025-CL_1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "201806": 0,
                    "201807": 0,
                    "201808": 0,
                    "201809": 0,
                    "201810": 0,
                    "201811": 0,
                    "201812": 0,
                    "201901": 0,
                    "201902": 0,
                    "201903": 0,
                    "201904": 0,
                    "201905": 0,
                    "201906": 0,
                    "201907": 0,
                    "201908": 0,
                    "201909": 0,
                    "201910": 0,
                    "201911": 0,
                    "format": "number",
                    "careerLevel": "Managing Director",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "Accenture Leadership - 2",
                            "careerID": "2-MD-10000025-CL_2"
                        },
                        {
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "Accenture Leadership - 3",
                            "careerID": "3-MD-10000025-CL_3"
                        },
                        {
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "Accenture Leadership - 4",
                            "careerID": "4-MD-10000025-CL_4"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "201806": 0,
                    "201807": 0,
                    "201808": 0,
                    "201809": 0,
                    "201810": 0,
                    "201811": 0,
                    "201812": 0,
                    "201901": 0,
                    "201902": 0,
                    "201903": 0,
                    "201904": 0,
                    "201905": 0,
                    "201906": 0,
                    "201907": 0,
                    "201908": 0,
                    "201909": 0,
                    "201910": 0,
                    "201911": 0,
                    "format": "number",
                    "careerLevel": "Senior Manager",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "5 - Senior Manager",
                            "careerID": "5-SM-10000050"
                        },
                        {
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "6 - Senior Manager",
                            "careerID": "6-SM-10000060"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "201806": 0,
                    "201807": 0,
                    "201808": 0,
                    "201809": 0,
                    "201810": 0,
                    "201811": 0,
                    "201812": 0,
                    "201901": 0,
                    "201902": 0,
                    "201903": 0,
                    "201904": 0,
                    "201905": 0,
                    "201906": 0,
                    "201907": 0,
                    "201908": 0,
                    "201909": 0,
                    "201910": 0,
                    "201911": 0,
                    "format": "number",
                    "careerLevel": "Manager",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                        "201806": 0,
                        "201807": 0,
                        "201808": 0,
                        "201809": 0,
                        "201810": 0,
                        "201811": 0,
                        "201812": 0,
                        "201901": 0,
                        "201902": 0,
                        "201903": 0,
                        "201904": 0,
                        "201905": 0,
                        "201906": 0,
                        "201907": 0,
                        "201908": 0,
                        "201909": 0,
                        "201910": 0,
                        "201911": 0,
                        "format": "number",
                        "careerL": "7 - Manager",
                        "careerID": "7-M-10000070"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "201806": 0,
                    "201807": 0,
                    "201808": 0,
                    "201809": 0,
                    "201810": 0,
                    "201811": 0,
                    "201812": 0,
                    "201901": 0,
                    "201902": 0,
                    "201903": 0,
                    "201904": 0,
                    "201905": 0,
                    "201906": 0,
                    "201907": 0,
                    "201908": 0,
                    "201909": 0,
                    "201910": 0,
                    "201911": 0,
                    "format": "number",
                    "careerLevel": "Consultant",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "8 - Consultant",
                            "careerID": "8-C-10000080"
                        },
                        {
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,
                            "201905": 0,
                            "201906": 0,
                            "201907": 0,
                            "201908": 0,
                            "201909": 0,
                            "201910": 0,
                            "201911": 0,
                            "format": "number",
                            "careerL": "9 - Consultant",
                            "careerID": "9-C-10000090"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "201806": 0,
                    "201807": 0,
                    "201808": 0,
                    "201809": 0,
                    "201810": 0,
                    "201811": 0,
                    "201812": 0,
                    "201901": 0,
                    "201902": 0,
                    "201903": 0,
                    "201904": 0,
                    "201905": 0,
                    "201906": 0,
                    "201907": 0,
                    "201908": 0,
                    "201909": 0,
                    "201910": 0,
                    "201911": 0,
                    "format": "number",
                    "careerLevel": "Analyst",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                            "201806": 0,
                            "201807": 0,
                            "201808": 0,
                            "201809": 0,
                            "201810": 0,
                            "201811": 0,
                            "201812": 0,
                            "201901": 0,
                            "201902": 0,
                            "201903": 0,
                            "201904": 0,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]


    var input2 = // iam trimming down this input due to 300000 character limit.

        [{
            "201609": 0,
            "201610": 0,
            "201611": 0,
            "201612": 0,
            "201701": 0,
            "201702": 0,
            "201703": 0,
            "201704": 0,
            "201705": 0,
            "201706": 0,
            "201707": 0,
            "201708": 0.5,
            "201709": 1,
            "201710": 1,
            "201711": 1,
            "201712": 1,
            "201801": 1,
            "201802": 1,
            "201803": 1.5,
            "201804": 2,
            "201805": 2,
            "201806": 2,
            "201807": 2,
            "201808": 2,
            "201809": 2,
            "201810": 2,
            "201811": 2,
            "201812": 2,
            "201901": 2,
            "201902": 2,
            "201903": 2,
            "201904": 2,
            "201905": 2,
            "201906": 2,
            "201907": 2,
            "201908": 2,
            "201909": 2,
            "201910": 2,
            "201911": 2,
            "fy17Q1": 0,
            "fy17": 0,
            "fy17Q2": 0,
            "fy17Q3": 0,
            "fy17Q4": 0.16666666666666666,
            "fy18Q1": 1,
            "fy18Q2": 1,
            "fy18": 0,
            "fy18Q3": 1.8333333333333333,
            "format": "number",
            "metric": "avgHeadCount",
            "careerLevelGroups": [{
                    "201609": 0,
                    "201610": 0,
                    "201611": 0,
                    "201612": 0,
                    "201701": 0,
                    "201702": 0,
                    "201703": 0,
                    "201704": 0,
                    "201705": 0,
                    "201706": 0,
                    "201707": 0,
                    "201708": 0,
                    "201709": 0,
                    "201710": 0,
                    "201711": 0,
                    "201712": 0,
                    "201801": 0,
                    "201802": 0,
                    "201803": 0.5,
                    "201804": 1,
                    "201805": 1,
                    "201806": 1,
                    "201807": 1,
                    "201808": 1,
                    "201809": 1,
                    "201810": 1,
                    "201811": 1,
                    "201812": 1,
                    "201901": 1,
                    "201902": 1,
                    "201903": 1,
                    "201904": 1,
                    "201905": 1,
                    "201906": 1,
                    "201907": 1,
                    "201908": 1,
                    "201909": 1,
                    "201910": 1,
                    "201911": 1,
                    "careerLevel": "Senior Manager",
                    "careerLevels": [{
                        "201609": 0,
                        "201610": 0,
                        "201611": 0,
                        "201612": 0,
                        "201701": 0,
                        "201702": 0,
                        "201703": 0,
                        "201704": 0,
                        "201705": 0,
                        "201706": 0,
                        "201707": 0,
                        "201708": 0,
                        "201709": 0,
                        "201710": 0,
                        "201711": 0,
                        "201712": 0,
                        "201801": 0,
                        "201802": 0,
                        "201803": 0.5,
                        "201804": 1,
                        "201805": 1,
                        "201806": 1,
                        "201807": 1,
                        "201808": 1,
                        "201809": 1,
                        "201810": 1,
                        "201811": 1,
                        "201812": 1,
                        "201901": 1,
                        "201902": 1,
                        "201903": 1,
                        "201904": 1,
                        "201905": 1,
                        "201906": 1,
                        "201907": 1,
                        "201908": 1,
                        "201909": 1,
                        "201910": 1,
                        "201911": 1,
                        "careerID": "6-SM-10000060",
                        "fy17Q1": 0,
                        "fy17": 0,
                        "fy17Q2": 0,
                        "fy17Q3": 0,
                        "fy17Q4": 0,
                        "fy18Q1": 0,
                        "fy18Q2": 0,
                        "fy18": 0,
                        "fy18Q3": 0.8333333333333334,
                        "format": "number"
                    }],
                    "fy17Q1": 0,
                    "fy17": 0,
                    "fy17Q2": 0,
                    "fy17Q3": 0,
                    "fy17Q4": 0,
                    "fy18Q1": 0,
                    "fy18Q2": 0,
                    "fy18": 0,
                    "fy18Q3": 0.8333333333333334,
                    "format": "number"
                },
                {
                    "201609": 0,
                    "201610": 0,
                    "201611": 0,
                    "201612": 0,
                    "201701": 0,
                    "201702": 0,
                    "201703": 0,
                    "201704": 0,
                    "201705": 0,
                    "201706": 0,
                    "201707": 0,
                    "201708": 0.5,
                    "201709": 1,
                    "201710": 1,
                    "201711": 1,
                    "201712": 1,
                    "201801": 1,
                    "201802": 1,
                    "201803": 1,
                    "201804": 1,
                    "201805": 1,
                    "201806": 1,
                    "201807": 1,
                    "201808": 1,
                    "201809": 1,
                    "201810": 1,
                    "201811": 1,
                    "201812": 1,
                    "201901": 1,
                    "201902": 1,
                    "201903": 1,


                }
            ]
        }]
```

But my output is coming as below which includes NULL , i am not able to figure out why this is happening.

output=

```
[{
        "201609": null,
        "201610": null,
        "201611": null,
        "201612": null,
        "201701": null,
        "201702": null,
        "201703": null,
        "201704": null,
        "201705": null,
        "201706": null,
        "201707": null,
        "201708": null,
        "201709": null,
        "201710": null,
        "201711": null,
        "201712": null,
        "201801": null,
        "201802": null,
        "201803": null,
        "201804": null,
        "201805": null,
        "201806": 2,
        "201807": 2,
        "201808": 2,
        "201809": 2,
        "201810": 2,
        "201811": 2,
        "201812": 2,
        "201901": 2,
        "201902": 2,
        "201903": 2,
        "201904": 2,
        "201905": 2,
        "201906": 2,
        "201907": 2,
        "201908": 2,
        "201909": 2,
        "201910": 2,
        "201911": 2,
        "format": "number",
        "metric": "avgHeadcount",
        "careerLevelGroups": [{
            "201609": null,
            "201610": null,
            "201611": null,
            "201612": null,
            "201701": null,
            "201702": null,
            "201703": null,
            "201704": null,
            "201705": null,
            "201706": null,
            "201707": null,
            "201708": null,
            "201709": null,
            "201710": null,
            "201711": null,
            "201712": null,
            "201801": null,
            "201802": null,
            "201803": null,
            "201804": null,
            "201805": null,
            "201806": 1,
            "201807": 1,
            "201808": 1,
            "201809": 1,
            "201810": 1,
            "201811": 1,
            "201812": 1,
            "201901": 1,
            "201902": 1,
            "201903": 1,
            "201904": 1,
            "201905": 1,
            "201906": 1,
            "201907": 1,
            "201908": 1,
            "201909": 1,
            "201910": 1,
            "201911": 1,
            "format": "number",
            "careerLevel": "Senior Managing Director",
            "careerLevels": [{
                "201609": null,
                "201610": null,
                "201611": null,
                "201612": null,
                "201701": null,
                "201702": null,


}]
```

What iam doing is as below :

```
function processJsonToSumValues(input, addingArray) {
  console.log("input", input);
  console.log("addingArray",addingArray);

  input.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log("item", item);
    console.log("index",index);
    for (let key in item) {
      // for numbers onlyyy
      if (typeof item[key] === 'number') {
        addingArray[index][key] = addingArray[index][key] + item[key]
      }
      if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
          console.log("input[index][key]", input[index][key]);
          console.log("addingArray[index][key]",addingArray[index][key]);
        processJsonToSumValues(input[index][key], addingArray[index][key])
      }
    }
  })
}
processJsonToSumValues(input2, input1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(input1));
```

Answer (score 0):

just a matter of setting default...

`NaN + 0 = NaN`

so when you use `addingArray[index][key] = addingArray[index][key] + item[key]` and the `addingArray[index][key]` value is not set on the first run/iteration, it isn't set.

to fix that, use `addingArray[index][key] = (addingArray[index][key] || 0) + item[key]` to set to 0 if not set.

```
function processJsonToSumValues(input, addingArray) {
  console.log("input", input);
  console.log("addingArray",addingArray);

  input.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log("item", item);
    console.log("index",index);
    for (let key in item) {
      // for numbers onlyyy
      if (typeof item[key] === 'number') {
        addingArray[index][key] = (addingArray[index][key] || 0) + item[key]
      }
      if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
          console.log("input[index][key]", input[index][key]);
          console.log("addingArray[index][key]",addingArray[index][key]);
        processJsonToSumValues(input[index][key], addingArray[index][key])
      }
    }
  })
}
```